# Proper Ordering of Assets in applcation.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have noticed that by varying the order of the called asset files in `application.js`, varies what asset will actually be loaded.

For example, my `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/2/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require raphael
//= require morris
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google 
//= require 'locations'
//= require 'campaigns'
//= require 'users'
```

In this present state, when navigating to the locations or campaigns pages, those files, `locations.js.coffee` and `campaigns.js.coffee` are loaded but in the users page the information from `users.js.coffee` is not loaded.

Now, if I change how the last three listed in applications.js are ordered to something like:

```
//= require 'users'
//= require 'locations'
//= require 'campaigns'
```

Then the `users.js.coffee` file is loaded but neither `locations.js.coffee` not `campaigns.js.coffee` is loaded.

Why is this the case? How can it be resolved?

**UPDATE: ADDED users, locations, campaigns, ".js.coffee" files:**

users.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  Morris.Line
    element: 'campaignTrendChart'
    data: [
      {y: '2012', a: 100}
      {y: '2011', a: 75}
      {y: '2010', a: 50}
      {y: '2009', a: 75}
      {y: '2008', a: 50}
      {y: '2007', a: 75}
      {y: '2006', a: 100}
    ]
    xkey: 'y'
    ykeys: ['a']
    labels: ['Series a']
   return
```

locations.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->

  # Create the table object for all methods
  table = $("#restaurantLocations").DataTable()

  # For selecting a restaruant and removing them
  $("#restaurantLocations tbody").on "click", "tr", ->
    if $(this).hasClass("selected")
      $(this).removeClass "selected"
    else
      table.$("tr.selected").removeClass "selected"
      $(this).addClass "selected"
    return

  # Button to delete restaurants
  $("#deleteRestaurant").click ->
    table.row(".selected").remove().draw false
    return

  return

  # Add a text input to each footer cell
  $("#restaurantLocations tfoot th").each ->
    title = $("#restaurantLocations thead th").eq($(this).index()).text()
    $(this).html "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Search " + title + "\" />"
    return

 # Apply the column specific filtering
  table.columns().eq(0).each (colIdx) ->
    $("input", table.column(colIdx).footer()).on "keyup change", ->
      table.column(colIdx).search(@value).draw()
      return

    return

  return



  $("#restaurantLocations tbody").on "click", "tr", ->
    $(this).toggleClass "selected"
  return

  $("#button").click ->
    alert table.rows(".selected").data().length + " row(s) selected"
    return

  return
```

campaigns.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->

  $('#campaign_category_ids').chosen()

  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker();

# Google maps
  handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
  handler.buildMap
    internal:
      id: "multi_markers"
  , ->
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
        lat: 43
        lng: 3.5
      }
      {
        lat: 45
        lng: 4
      }
      {
        lat: 47
        lng: 3.5
      }
      {
        lat: 49
        lng: 4
      }
      {
        lat: 51
        lng: 3.5
      }
    ])
    handler.bounds.extendWith markers
    handler.fitMapToBounds()
  return

  $('#selectRestaurantsForCampaign').DataTable()

    # Create the table object for all methods
  table = $("#selectRestaurantsForCampaign").DataTable()

  # Add a text input to each footer cell
  $("#selectRestaurantsForCampaign tfoot th").each ->
    title = $("#restaurantLocations thead th").eq($(this).index()).text()
    $(this).html "<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Search " + title + "\" />"
  return

 # Apply the column specific filtering
  table.columns().eq(0).each (colIdx) ->
    $("input", table.column(colIdx).footer()).on "keyup change", ->
      table.column(colIdx).search(@value).draw()
      return

    return

  return


  # For selecting, will need to extend to select all
  $("#selectRestaurantsForCampaign tbody").on "click", "tr", ->
    $(this).toggleClass "selected"
  return

  # Will extend to select all.. to get all present filtered locations
  $("#selectAll").click ->
    alert table.rows(".selected").data().length + " row(s) selected"
    return

  return
```

Comment: Remove the three last require and add this as last line `//= require_tree .`. And tell me what happens.

Comment: @AlejandroBabio Now only the `campaigns.js.coffee` files load/render, `locations.js.coffee` and `users.js.coffee` do not load nor do the scripts render in screen...

Comment: Please, check the server log and the browser console looking for errors.

Comment: At the terminal where you start the rails server, scroll up until find somthing like `Started GET "/"` Start at this point and scroll down looking for error messages. At the browser with F12.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63652/discussion-between-alejandro-babio-and-sauron).

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the chat invite. Can we try again for 9am eastern time on Sunday, October 26?

Comment: @AlejandroBabio I updated the question with my js.coffee code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the same issue that I had with morris.

Use this: on users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('#campaignTrendChart').map ->
    Morris.Line
      ... # the rest of your code
```

Morris fails if it can't find the html element. I tried this code with `.each` instead of `.map`, but I think for only one element you must use this one.

And on campaigns.js.coffee

```
$('#multi_markers').map ->
   handler = Gmaps.build("Google")
   handler.buildMap
      ... # the rest of your code
```

I think this will do the trick.

Morris and Gmaps needs the html element to be present at the page when they search for it. This workaround prevents a call to Morris or Gmaps if the element is not present.

In response to the request of sauron in chat:

If you have several elements that works with Morris, you can group them with a class (could be .morris_line), also each element must hold its Morris data. And you can do some type of DRY like this:

at the view:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, class: 'chart_bars', id: "chart_person_#{@person.id}",
data: {bar: chart_data}) do %>
```

your js must be something like this:

```
$('.chart_bars').each ->
   Morris.bar 
     element: this.id
     data: $(this).data('bar')
     ... # rest of the params for morris
```

Comment: I tried that but the code in the `users.js.coffee` didn't render

Comment: How about 12pm eastern time for a chat?

Comment: I'm sorry, this time I'm missed your invite. At 4pm today, click [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63652/discussion-between-alejandro-babio-and-sauron), if you can, if not click anyway. I'll leave the messages there.

Comment: It's not 12pm yet, but I'll just keep the chat open

Comment: Tell me by the chat if you need more details.